# Fixing broken wrought iron gate

Tags: gates

The Fleur-de-lis shape on top of iron rod of the gate broke off during tree trimming about 3 yrs back. I have been attaching it every year or so with J+B weld. However, it seems fall off after sometime. Is there a more permanent way to fix it? Or, do need to find a welder etc..

Comment: How about a picture so we can see what you see.

Comment: If you can remove the gate and take to local garage or welder, then cost should be quite low.  Much less than if they need to come to you

Comment: When you post the picture show the bottom of the shape where it connects with the gate, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more permanent way to fix it? Or, do need to find a welder etc..

You've practically answered your own question. Yes, there is a more permanent way to fix it - actual welding, not an epoxy product with "weld" misleadingly in its name and a bunch of implausible miraculous claims elsewhere on the package. Brazing would probably also work fine. and might be preferable if the decoration is cast iron, rather than actual wrought iron.